# What does "Tech 1pt" and "Tech 2pt" mean?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

I know that when I kill various enemies, I get experience points that help me level my characters. However, sometimes I see "Tech 1pt" or "Tech 2pt" after hitting (not necessarily killing) an enemy. What does that mean? What does "Tech" do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Tech" is bonus XP earned during a fight. It's generally awarded for succeeding in... Unecessary areas, to put it bluntly.

An example would be Wakka in the beginning. When he yells, "Take this!" and throws his blitz ball at you, you can hit it back to him for bonus XP in the form of Tech points.

There are several other ways to earn tech points (parrying an attack, exploiting an enemies weakness, etc.).

The [Wikia](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_Points) gives a few more (better) examples than mine, though.

Comment: Ah, so they're not separate from XP, they are just bonus XP with a weirdly different name?

Comment: Correct. They go toward your level progress, and can actually provide a pretty substantial boost to your overall gain.  I would play "tennis" with Wakka and manage to be level 10 before getting to Traverse Town.

Comment: Fun fact: You can use this to power level on Destiny Island quickly. Got up to level 35 by just deflecting Tidus' attacks.

Comment: @Ktash That's where I power leveled early. On Wakka. Go Final Fantasy X!

Comment: I think I actually powerleveled off of Rikku, but I might be wrong, it was whoever was up on the little island you had to jump to, really easy to get lots of tech points if your able to keep him in the air.